# Automatically loading a bibliography file depending on buffer filename

Tags: org-mode, reftex-mode, filenames

I use `org-mode` to write a paper, with RefTeX as minor-mode to insert quotations from a BibTeX (`.bib`) file.

RefTeX needs to be told which `.bib` file to use. This is done by assigning a value to `reftex-default-bibliography`.

I would like a `.bib` file to be automatically assigned, depending on the name of the file I am editing. For example, if I edit a paper called `the-life-of-ants.org`, RefTeX should automatically load `the-life-of-ants.bib`, stored in the same folder as the `.org` file.

If no `.bib` file with the same name as the `.org` file is stored in the local directory, my default bibliography file should be loaded instead.

This is in Emacs 25.3.1 on Windows 7.

I've tried a function that is called whenever `org-mode` is loaded, using a hook in the last line of the code below. (The code also does some unrelated stuff, like changing the default keybinding for inserting citations to make it compatible with org-mode standard bindings.)

```
(defun org-mode-reftex-setup ()
  (load-library "reftex") 
  (and (buffer-file-name)
  (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name))
  (reftex-parse-all))
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c (") 'reftex-citation) ; key-binding
  (if (file-exists-p (concat (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name) ".bib")) ; either use local .bib file
      (progn 
        (setq reftex-default-bibliography
              (convert-standard-filename (concat (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name) ".bib")))
        (message "Local bib-file loaded.")) ; or use default .bib file
    (progn
      (setq reftex-default-bibliography
            '"c:\\foo\\bar\\baz\\References.bib")
      (message "No bib-file found. Using default bibliography."))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-mode-reftex-setup)
```

Upon visiting an Org file, the function is executed as expected, and the correct value (it seems) is assigned to `reftex-default-bibliography` -- or is it?

`M-x eval-expression (message reftex-default-bibliography)` tells me:

```
c:\foo\bar\local-bibliography.bib
"c:\\foo\\bar\\local-bibliography.bib"
```

I don't understand why two lines are produced, one with quotes and double-backslashes (which are needed, I think, to correctly parse file-paths in MS Windows, and which are produced by `convert-standard-filename`), and one without.

However, `M-x eval-expression reftex-default-bibliography` tells me only:

```
"c:\\foo\\bar\\local-bibliography.bib"
```

which seems to be correct.

And yet, when I try to insert a reference, I get an error:

`reftex-locate-file: Wrong type argument: stringp, 99`

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Why two lines are produced: `message` returns its argument and as a side effect prints that argument to the minibuffer (and the *Messages* buffer).  The first line is the side-effect and the second is the argument being returned.

Comment: It seems at some point, a function named `reftex-locate-file` is given 99 as an argument while it expects a string.  You could `(setq debug-on-error t)` to get a stack trace and get more information.